# jquery datepicker - beforeShowDay problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".datepicker").each(function() {

     $(this).datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){ return [$(this).parent().find("span.days").html(), ""] },

     });
   });

  });
```

With this body code...

```
<div>
<span class="days">(date.getDay() == 1 || date.getDay() == 4)</span>
<input type="text" class="datepicker">
</div>


<div>
<span class="days">(date.getDay() == 2 || date.getDay() == 5)</span>
<input type="text" class="datepicker">
</div>
```

What I want to be able to do is have each datepicker have different days pickable.

The way i'm trying to do this (putting the varying part of the beforeShowDay code in a span) may not be the most elegant so feel free to take my code apart and change it if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an object keeping the pickable days, like this:

```
var pickable = { dp1: [1, 4], dp2: [2, 5] };
$('.datepicker').each(function() {
  $(this).datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){ 
        var day = date.getDay(), days = pickable[this.id];
        return [$.inArray(day, days) > -1, ""];
    }
  });
});​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/wx7jd/).  The `dp1` and `dp2` are IDs of the controls..or any attribute you can map really, like this:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="dp1">
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="dp2">
```

The concept is pretty simple, take the ID to get the array of days for this picker, then use [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) to see if the day we're on is in that array.  If these day selections may be shared, don't use an ID, instead do something like `data-pickerType` for the attribute, and replace `this.id` with `$(this).attr("data-pickerType")` in the code above.

*Note:* I left the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) intact because I know you need it for reasons outside the current question.