# How do I restrict multiple DatePickers to certain days?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a form with lots of different date fields, and the datepicker is working perfect, however some of the fields need to be restricted by certain days.

i.e. one can only select mondays, the other can only select saturdays/sundays and the other can only select saturdays.

is it possible this can be done on one form?

I understand how to restrict the days, have done it so only mondays can be selected but dont know how to customise so individual date fields you can only select other days.

Help would be much appreciated

EDIT :

I am using Drupal and Webform, with JqueryUI Datepicker.  Ive used this code successfully to restrict selections to monday, however that is obviously across the whole form and I have other date fields that I want to make other kinds of restrictions on.

```
onlyMon: function(date) {
        if (date.getDay(1) == 1) {
            return [true, ''];
        } else {
            return [false, ''];
        }
    },
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Consider writing a more descriptive question title and adding a few pieces of code and details about what components you're using, environment, anything that might actually help us help you. - edit: Thanks meagar, not having proper edit privileges is a bit hampering sometimes. ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery datepicker - beforeShowDay problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812203/jquery-datepicker-beforeshowday-problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this something like you're looking for?

[jquery datepicker - beforeShowDay problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812203/jquery-datepicker-beforeshowday-problem)

Comment: Tom looks like it, let me try it out and let you know.  Thanks!

Comment: Tom, do you know if you have to use the input ID? or could you use class?

Comment: You'd need to use the id in this case. There might be a way to create a work around which uses class, but it'd probably involve quite a lot of messing around.